Multiple Table Xref Design
Looking for the "correct" way to model this data. I have unique values in one table, which can be associated with entities stored in multiple other tables. I have a contrived example here that reflects the actual problem I'm trying to solve.
Tags are unique and can be applied to many entities, let's call them MacGuffins, Placeholders, and Widgets. An entity can be tagged with zero, one, or multiple tags.
A tag is unique, in that it's TagValue and TagType (not in the pictures, sorry) is unique across its own table. An entity tagged can only be tagged once with a given tag. If a Tag's value is modified, that change must be reflected across all entities tagged with it.
Certain tags may not be available for all entity types. So, a given tag may be marked as available to MacGuffins and Widgets, but not to Placeholders.
What I'm questioning is the way to relate the data in the DB, for performance, ease or efficiency of querying, and not box ourselves in for potential changes in the future. The two options that have been conceived are having an xref table for each of the entities, or a single xref table with a column specifying which entity type the relationship refers to. Any potential alternative to these are quite welcome. I have my own bias, but have both types of patterns (or maybe anti-patterns) in a legacy application and there does not appear to be glaring problems with either one.



The correct thing to do in your case is probably Option 1: separate join tables for each entity.
Note though that the WidgetTagsId etc columns are not necessary. A join table should just have a composite primary key made up of the two foreign-key columns.

Option 2 is not correctly normalized: it would require a complex CHECK constraint to ensure that only one type was ever joined. And it would be ambiguous as to which type to join on, so foreign keys wouldn't work.
The only way this could work is if the entities were in a Polymorphic Association. This is usually done with parent and child tables. For example:
CREATE TABLE Tag (
    TagId bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    TagValue nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE Entity (
    EntityId bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    EntityType tinyint NOT NULL CHECK (EntityType BETWEEN 1 AND 10),
    UNIQUE (EntityId, EntityType)
);



CREATE TABLE EntityTag (
    EntityId bigint REFERENCES Entity (EntityId),
    TagId bigint REFERENCES Tag (TagId),
    PRIMARY KEY (EntityId, TagId)
);


CREATE TABLE Widget (
    EntityId bigint
    EntityType AS CAST(1 AS tinyint),
    Name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (EntityId, EntityType),
    FOREIGN KEY (EntityId, EntityType) REFERENCES Entity (EntityId, EntityType)
);



CREATE TABLE MacGuffin (
    EntityId bigint
    EntityType AS CAST(2 AS tinyint),
    Name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (EntityId, EntityType),
    FOREIGN KEY (EntityId, EntityType) REFERENCES Entity (EntityId, EntityType)
);

Note how in a polymorphic association, the entity type is enforced across tables via foreign key and check constraints, and computed columns.
Now the EntityTag table can refer to any entity. But this would only make sense if the entities really do have some kind of "base type". Just the fact that they all reference Tag does not make that so.

If is possible to merge the 3 tables you should try it, but in case is not here is an option:
    -- Create a table for the rules

CREATE TABLE TagRule (
    TagRuleId TINYINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ,RuleDescription VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE
    ,WidgetAvailable BIT NOT NULL
    ,MacGuffinAvailable BIT NOT NULL
    ,PlaceHolderAvailable BIT NOT NULL)

INSERT TagRule VALUES ('All available', 1, 1, 1)
INSERT TagRule VALUES ('Only for Widget', 1, 0, 0)
INSERT TagRule VALUES ('Only for MacGuffin', 0, 1, 0)

CREATE TABLE Tag (
    TagId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED NOT NULL
    ,TagName VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE
    ,TagRuleId TINYINT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TagRule(TagRuleId))

    -- Using the first option

CREATE TABLE Widget (
    WidgetId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED NOT NULL
    ,Name VARCHAR(100) )

CREATE TABLE WidgetTag (
    WidgetTagId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED NOT NULL
    ,WidgetId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Widget(WidgetID)
    ,TagId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Tag(TagId) )

    -- Select to show the tags (Widget)

SELECT
    T.TagId
    ,T.TagName
FROM Tag T
JOIN TagRule TR ON T.TagRuleId = TR.TagRuleId
WHERE
    TR.WidgetAvailable = 1

